# Service attribute decorator with ANY additional property causes "could not parse package" issue on Android marshmallow

Tags: android, service, xamarin.android, attributes, android-manifest

I'm trying to create a JobService with Xamarin.  Because I can't just plug the permission into the AndroidManifest, I have to add it as an attribute property and when doing that, it causes parsing errors when trying to install on marshmallow devices.  I also can not debug with a marshmallow device when I have that attribute decorator in place.  Here's my JobService declaration:

```
    [Service(Name = "com.something.someapp", Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
    public class HandlePushNotificationJobService : JobService
    { 
....
    }
```

I also have another service (just a regular service, not a JobService) and I've tried adding just the "name" property to it, and the same issue occurs - parsing error when installing a signed apk, and can't debug to the device directly.

This is two pretty major bugs I've uncovered in Xamarin in as many days.  Is there some other way to add these service declarations to the manifest directly?  When I try just putting in the xml node to the manifest and removing the attribute, it causes problems on devices that DO work with the attribute because it can't find the service reference (I've tried just about every way to reference the path I can think of (my package name + class name, namespace + class name, relative paths + class name etc)).

Surely someone else has come across this and the Xamarin team (MS team) is aware of this?

Any fixes for this?

TIA

Comment: i have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for hours on this last night and couldn't find anything.  Right after I posted this, I thought I'd give one more search a try and found this:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/108772/replacing-services-with-jobs-in-android-oreo-8-0

MSiccDev had the solution (to remove the name property).  So this works for me:

```
    [Service(Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
    public class HandlePushNotificationJobService : JobService
    { 
....
    }
```

Comment: nope if i delete the name decorator it still doesn't f'in work. what is the correct path, do you know?

Comment: are you trying to get this to work for a Job Service?  If so, did you add the Permission property to the attribute above the class decoration like I showed in my answer?

Comment: to answer your question, there is no "correct" path because it's variable depending on your version of android.  This is why you need to let the compiler generate the path for you at build time and the only way to do that is to leave the name parameter off.  Essentially putting the name parameter on the attribute is the same as hard coding the name/path of the service which gets written in to the manifest and since older versions of android don't work with incorrect casing (I believe lower case doesn't work), you have to let the compiler do the magic for you.

Comment: turns out someone assigned a string to an int class variable in the jobservice class(i was reimplementing code someone had assured me would work, just had to convert intentservice to jobservice). compile and build didn't catch it because ofc the string was coming from strings.xml and being converted to int on the fly. Xamarin build process completely swallowed the error for whatever reason and instead gave me JNIHandle could not be found. had to dive into the generated java code in the obj folder to figure out this issue

Comment: glad you got it sorted.